# Chrome Extension to Take String and Place It in Specific Website Field

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I am trying to solve a problem at my place of employment. I am entirely new to programming so I may be in over my head, however this is what I was able to come up with.

We have a card reader we are trying to use with WaveApps invoicing software. There is no native support for this.
The card reader acts as a USB keyboard which creates an input when a card is swiped in the following format: %B0000000000000000^LASTNAME/FIRSTNAME^YYMM#################################
So the swipe always registers with %B, then the 16 digit card number. Then the '^' character followed by the last name a '/' character, the first name, the '^' character followed by the two digit year and two digit month.

Meanwhile, the website for payments looks like the following:

WaveApps Payment Screenshot

[image: 1]

If I swipe the card with the cursor in the card number field, it puts in seemingly random digits.

So, I decided to create a Chrome extension which could take the input and put it in these fields for me.

The extension looks like this:

Chrome Extension for CC Payments

[image: 2]

The basic idea is that the user would swipe the card while the cursor is in the extension field, the button is clicked and the website gets autopopulated with the correct information. Here is the code I have used for the extension.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('submit2');
  
  checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(
                tabs[0].id
                ,{code:
                    function() {
                        //Get fields with card info
                        var inputField = document.getElementById('submit');
                        var inputValue = inputField.value;
                        
                        //Chop up card info and store into individual variables
                        var cardNumber = inputValue.slice(2, 18);
                        var nameStartIndex = inputValue.indexOf("^") + 1;
                        var nameEndIndex = inputValue.indexOf("^", nameStartIndex);
                        var name = inputValue.slice(nameStartIndex, nameEndIndex).replace("/", " ");
                        var dateStartIndex = inputValue.indexOf("^", nameEndIndex) + 1;
                        var year = inputValue.slice(dateStartIndex, dateStartIndex + 2);
                        var month = inputValue.slice(dateStartIndex + 2, dateStartIndex + 4);
                        var date = month + year;
                        
                        //Get fields to put values into
                        var cardNumber_f = document.getElementById("CreditCardNumber");
                        var name_f = document.getElementById("NameOnCard");
                        var date_f = document.getElementById("ExpiryDate");

                        cardNumber_f.value = cardNumber;
                        name_f.value = name;
                        date_f.value = date;
                    }
                }
            );
        });
    });
});
```

No matter how many times I have done this, nothing happens. I click submit and it's like the code isn't communicating with the site properly. I feel a bit lost.

I have also tried making this as a Userscript but that was a lost cause.

Edit:
Here is my manifest.json

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Card Swipe to Wave",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "This extension allows you to use a card swipe reader on WaveApps",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage", "<all_urls>"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*.waveapps.com/*", "http://*.waveapps.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.mini.js","content.js","popup.js"],
    "html": ["popup.html"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["popup.js"]
  }
}
```

Here is the html I am using

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Submit Form</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Click after swiping</h2>
    <input type="text" id="submit">
    <button id="submit2">Submit</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: paste input string and expect output string.

Comment: add `beforeinput` add eventlistener and manipulate input before browser process it.

Comment: Start by debugging the code. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu. Also show your html and manifest.json because there could be dozens of things specified incorrectly.

Comment: popup.html:1 Error handling response: TypeError: Error in invocation of tabs.executeScript(optional integer tabId, extensionTypes.InjectDetails details, optional function callback): Error at parameter 'details': Error at property 'code': Invalid type: expected string, found function.
This is what the debugger tells me